# How to combine regex lookarounds into logical groups

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am using this regex pattern, consisting of a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead, to split the words of strings that are formatted in Pascal case:

`(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`

This can be used to split, for example, "MyPascalCasedString" into ["My", "Pascal", "Cased", "String"].

Now I would like to modify the pattern to consider certain special cases: fixed words that look like pascal case but are considered a single word and should not be split, for example "LibreOffice". I tried with additional negative lookarounds:
`(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])(?<!Libre)(?!Office)`
That works: "ThisIsLibreOffice" is split into ["This", "Is", "LibreOffice"]. However, words that only start with "Libre" or end with "Office" are also not split:
"ThisIsLibreSoftware" -> ["This", "Is", "LibreSoftware"]
"ThisIsAnotherOffice" -> ["This", "Is", "AnotherOffice"]

How can I combine the negative lookarounds so that they only match together, and still in combination with the two positive lookarounds?

Comment: Please check the last paragraph in my updated answer pointing out a bug in my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only way I believe this can be done.

```
(?<=[a-z])(?<!Libre(?=Office))(?=[A-Z])
```

https://regex101.com/r/hQ306t/1

```
 (?<= [a-z] )         # Behind a lower case
 (?<!                 # Here in the middle: ( but could be anywhere )
    Libre                # No 'Libre' behind, and
    (?= Office )         # No 'Office' ahead
 )
 (?= [A-Z] )          # Ahead a upper case
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is how to extend it with other special cases like "OpenProject": `(?<=[a-z])(?<!Libre(?=Office))(?<!Open(?=Project))(?=[A-Z])`

Comment: Not the only way (see comment on "Good Night Nerd Pride"'s answer), but a good one!

Answer (score 2):

It works when you "or" the additional look arounds:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])((?<!Libre)|(?!Office))
```

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/SpeVjm/1

In order to add more special cases like e.g. "OpenProject":

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])((?<!Libre)(?<!Open)|(?!Office)(?!Project))
```

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/zoM5fs/1

As you can see it doesn't scale very well and will quickly get out of hand. I'd probably rather merge the special cases back together in a post-processing step.

**Update**: I just noticed my proposed regex has a flaw. It will also detect "LibreProject" and "OpenOffice" as words. So strictly speaking this is not a correct answer.

Comment: It works correctly with a slight modification, grouping the special cases like so: `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])((?<!Libre)|(?!Office))((?<!Office)|(?!Project))` A disadvantage is that the grouping parentheses also act as capturing groups, interspersing the result of the split string with empty strings. Making them non-capturing groups solves that problem: `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])(?:(?<!Libre)|(?!Office))(?:(?<!Office)|(?!Project))` Overall, sln's answer (and your extension of it) is more concise so I'm making that the accepted answer.